# Firebase error: the default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui

I'm trying to implement firebase cloud messaging in my app, i included some logic and i tried building and i'm getting this error.

`Thread 1: "The default FirebaseApp instance must be configured before the default Authinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure this is to call FirebaseApp.configure() in the App Delegate's application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) (or the @main struct's initializer in SwiftUI)."`

this is my code

i tried calling FirebaseApp.configure() in init, and in application method, but i still get the same error. I searched to see some solutions but non of these worked out

```
`import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import GoogleSignIn
import UserNotifications


@available(iOS 15.0, *)
@main
struct iGrow_GoalsApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    @StateObject var viewModel1 = AppViewModel()
    
    init() {
        //setupAuthentication()
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel1)
        }
    }
    
}

class AppDelegate : NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    
    override init() {
            //FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
    
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {
        
        // Handle other custom URL types.
        
        // If not handled by this app, return false.
        return false
    }
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) async -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
    
    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
    
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.self.window = window
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
    }
    
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    
  // [START refresh_token]
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")

    let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(
      name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
      object: nil,
      userInfo: dataDict
    )
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
  }

  // [END refresh_token]
}

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
extension iGrow_GoalsApp {
    private func setupAuthentication() {
      FirebaseApp.configure()
      //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    }
}`
```

Comment: When using SwiftUI application lifecycle, the `@main` `init` runs before  any methods of the `UIApplicationDelegateAdapter` class. You should remove the app delegate adapter and do all of your setup in the `@main` `init` or remove the `@main` `init` and do everything in the app delegate adapter